# Read More Button Not Responding To Click

Tags: themes

Below is my code in which everything is working fine except when clicking read more button it's doing nothing

```
<?php get_header() ; ?>

<section class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <article class="blog">
                      <div class="blog-meta">
                          <h2 class="blog-meta-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ; ?>"><?php the_title() ; ?></a></h2>
                            <p class="blog-meta-detail">
                              Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> 
                              on <?php the_time('F j, Y'); ?>
                              Category <?php the_category(', ') ; ?>
                              Tag  <?php if ( is_tag() ) {
                                         the_tags('',', ','');
                                           } else {
                                      echo("No Tags Found");
                                      } ?> 
                            </p>
                      </div> <!-- .blog-meta -->
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                      <div class="blog-img">
                         <?php the_post_thumbnail('full',array(
                                'class' => 'img-responsive',
                            )); ?>
                        </div> <!-- .blog-img -->
                <?php endif ; ?> <!-- if ends here of thumbnail -->
                      <div class="blog-excerpt">
                          <?php the_excerpt() ; ?>
                      </div> <!-- .blog-excerpt -->
                      <div class="blog-more">
                           <button class="btn btn-primary" href="<?php the_permalink() ; ?>">Read More</button>
                      </div> <!-- .blog-more -->
                      <div class="blog-hr">
                          <hr>
                      </div> <!-- .blog-hr -->
                    </article> <!-- .blog -->
                <?php endwhile; else : ?> <!-- while ends here of post loop and else starts -->
                     <article class="blog">
                          <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts found yo can always start writing' ); ?></p>
                     </article> <!-- .blog -->
                <?php endif; ?> <!-- if ends here post loop -->      
            </div> <!-- .col-sm-8 -->
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <?php get_sidebar() ; ?>
            </div> <!-- .col-sm-4 -->
        </div> <!-- .row -->
</section> <!-- .container -->

<?php get_footer() ; ?>
```

looks like dev in dev tool also link is showing correctly on read more button
[image]
thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked your code and site.

Just replace "button" with "a href" in your code for "Read More" and it will work. Try below code -

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://project11-cannelflow1.c9users.io/2017/01/17/hello-world/">Read More</a>
```

Comment: let me try that

Comment: Sorry for that, I have revised my answer. Please check.

Comment: Glad it helped. Can you please vote and mark my answer as useful :)

Comment: already did that accepted the answer upvoted also but it said my upvoted is only visible after I cross 15 reputation

Answer (score 0):

You can use another trick if you like to keep the button style.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick='location.href="<?php the_permalink() ; ?>"'>Read More</button>
```